# Null is not a subtype of type String

Tags: flutter

Hello I’m new to flutter
I’m trying to retrieve the user data from his email but i got this error [Null is not a subtype of type String]
The data I’m trying to retrieve is not null
This is my code

```
class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {

late User user;

final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

late User signedInUser;

var id;



var email;

 var name;

var age;

  var sex;

  @override
  void initState() {

 super.initState();
    onRefresh(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
    getCurrentUser();

}

  onRefresh(userCare) 
{

setState(()
 {
      user = userCare;
    });
  }

  void getCurrentUser() 
{
    try {         
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        signedInUser = user;
        email = signedInUser.email;
        id = signedInUser.uid;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void getData() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
   
 if (doc["email"] == signedInUser.email) {
      name = doc['name'];
      age = doc['age'];
      sex = doc['sex'];
      print(doc['name']);
    }
  });
});
```

}

This is my data
I want to retrieve then but i can’t because it says null how to fix the error?

[this is the data I’m trying to retrieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WLfj.jpg)

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWICz.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the Traceback error.

Comment: On what point the error comes?

Comment: It is on the build widget  if say Text(name),

Comment: i have edit my answer again

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Code:

```
void getData() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .get()
                .then((value) {
              for(var doc in value.docs) {
           
         if (doc["email"] == signedInUser.email) {
              name = doc.data()['name'];
              age = doc.data()['age'];
              sex = doc.data()['sex'];
              print(doc.data()['name']);
            }
            }
          });
}
```

Comment: I did what you said but it gives me error

Comment: you also have to set the await before you use the function: `await getData();`

Comment: I can’t use doc.data()[‘name’]

Comment: i have edit my answer again